# What's the easiest way to set a date limit until an application can be used?

Tags: android

I would like to release a beta version of my app, but I would like to set and end date hardcoded in the code.

How can I do that easily? Is there an entry point that is fired before any of the activities?

Comment: Why no just test the date during onCreate()? and if the date is expired just show a message and otherwise process with the normal initialisation?

Comment: Remember that this method can be easily defeated by the user changing the date on their phone.

Comment: When creating your app keys I remember being able to change the time of expiry - maybe your could use this method...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "entry point" of an Android app, before all activities is [Application.onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()). I would go for what Sebi commented - check the date in launcher Activity's onCreate().

Answer (score 1):

You can test the system date like Sebi said, and see if the user allows Network date/time update. This way, the date is correct and you can see if your period expired :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#AUTO_TIME